# fop 0.20.5 and xslt 2.0?

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

does fop 0.20.5 support xslt 2.0? I have not been able to find the answer to this anywhere.

I have a 1.0 xslt document and I want to add a regular expression section to it. I have read that I can make a small block of this document into xslt 2.0 while leaving the rest in 1.0 as long as there is a backwards compatible processor. Will 0.20.5 or any version of fop support this? If not, what will. This is for xml to pdf document.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are unrelated. FOP is an XSL-FO processor. In order to use XSLT 2.0, you need to make sure you use a 2.0 XSLT processor.

FOP won't know if your XSL-FO was created using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: If I understand it correctly it is an xsl document (all xsl or fo blocks) but has a xlst extention because it is being used to format xml into a pdf. when I try using <xsl:analyze-string select="$textValue" regex="[.*\s*(Table.*)\s*.*]"> I get the error: "Could not find function: regex-group" which appears to be supported by xslt 2.0 but not 1.0

Comment: Yes, support for regular expressions is an XSLT 2.0 thing.